# Почему не удаляется символ из строки?

Tags: php

Есть строка вида:TW-227Б (цв.3-белый, 36) Туфли ортопедические детские

В ней мне нужно выцепить 36(число может быть разное)

Делаю разбиение и замену символа, но всеравно получается `36)`

```
$size = explode(" ", $arFields['PREVIEW_TEXT']);
$size_val = str_replace(')', '', $size['2']);
```

Comment: Видимо там какой-то другой символ, а не скобка

Comment: либо результат смотрят в `size[2]` а не `size_val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `regexp` - регулярные выражения, они помогут Вам в таких ситуациях

```php
<?php
$size = "TW-227Б (цв.3-белый, 36) Туфли ортопедические детские";
$size_val = 0;
if ( preg_match_all("/\S+ \(\S+\, (\d+)\) \S+/", $size, $matches) && is_array( $matches ) && count( $matches ) == 2 && is_array( $matches[1] ) && count( $matches[1] ) == 1 ) {
    $size_val = $matches[1][0];
}

echo $size_val;
```